# how to display page title only for child category pages

Tags: categories, title, children

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am just learning PHP and Wordpress. It's probably very simple.

I have a site where the top-level nav is all parent categories, with the child categories as dropdowns. The pages are all pulling from category.php.

On the child category pages, I would like to display the current child category page title (single_cat_title, I think) for styling, but I want to exclude this feature on the parent category pages.

I've been trying to write this very simply using get_the_category() as per this example in the codex:

`$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check wherever you're displaying the title:

```
//Anything greater than 0 means the category has parents, 0 means no parent, child category
if($category->category_parent > 0){
    echo $category[0]->cat_name;
}
```

This should help.

Comment: thanks Rutwick. So I dropped `
      $category = get_the_category();
      if ($category->category_parent > 0) { ?>
          <h1><?php $category[0]->cat_name; 
      } ?>
      </h1>` into my template, but nothing prints. Am I missing something? One thing I realized is that all the posts are assigned to multiple categories - could that be messing it up? (With the appropriate php tags open and close)

Comment: Try a `print_r` on `$category` to check if its right

Comment: Hi Rutwick - thank you again, that helped me work it out.